# Whatsapp PHP api receiving encoded message

Tags: php, whatsapp, whatsapi

I am using [Whatsapp PHP api](https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/) to send and receive messages.

When using my own phone number I am getting the message correctly, but using a friend's number sends an encrypted message. I got the issue on [github](https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/issues/109).

```
$debug = true;
$username = '91xxxxxxxxxxx';
$password = "L9Djoxxxx+/HxxxxxWK3X24="; 
$nickname = 'SG'; 
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $nickname, $debug);
$w->connect();
$w->loginWithPassword($password);
$w->sendSetProfilePicture("demo/venom.jpg");
$s= $w->pollMessage();
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
      print($m->NodeString(""));
}
```

Here is one encoded message:

```
<message from="91xxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="wsyC+kzW5JJv2" offline="0" t="1444469647" notify="Bikash">
  <enc v="1" type="pkmsg">3ýš²!øbƒÈÌl`¹$EÂ š‚A¹“"´®ä¾ì3Žvfx!    ?CgŸÙT×‚T¯Œp¶ìì.»ÓÊ¿~†6â…<"B3
!¶ÇIOÂóK†B(A=q”Ysþ¥(nrÎÏ(­™‚jg"$4b’¸=Ç—j|HûS§³R(„Í¼0</enc>
</message>
```

Comment: have you changed the whatsapp password accordingly with the phone number??

Comment: FYI : **if the number is registered newly, whatsapp server will send the message in an encrypted format!!!
for old registered numbers it will remain unencrypted!**

Comment: yes. I am able to receive image and videos correct but only getting text message encoded.

Comment: What do you mean by registered number?

Comment: Which version of the API are you using?

Comment: i think its 2.5.4. https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/

Comment: as they said the issue is resolved in previous versions of the API..

Comment: I have tried all versions they had, but did not working...

Comment: encoding (UTF-8) issue

Comment: if the number is registered newly, whatsapp server will send the message in an encrypted format!!!
for old registered numbers it will remain unencrypted!

https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/issues/109#issuecomment-63290954

Comment: @NanaPartykar do you want me to change character encoding... to UTF-8

Comment: Can you post a small example of the encrypted image ?

Comment: @PedroLobito i have added one..

Comment: I thought WhatsApp encryption depends on the phone's OS?? (iPhone has no encryption, Android has,..) rather than on the age of the number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API changes ([website](https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsApp-incoming-updates#17-nov-2014)) this issue started 17 nov.

> 17 Nov, 2014 Better encryption, more work for us!
>
> Is not as easy to implement the 'encrypt' feature as i thought.
>   WhatsApp has done a nice work this time (at least for now). We are
>   working hard on this, and it will take time to us to implement this
>   feature.
>
> WhatsApp is using axolotl from WhisperSystems, you can check here.
>
> We know more or less how it works, but as i said, this will take time
>   for us. So be patient. We'll update you as we continue on this.
>
> Regards,
>
> The WhatsAPI Official Team

It should be solved at the current moment:

> 27 Dec, 2014 We did it!
>
> It really has been a long time since we went to work on WhatsApp
>   encryption, but we have finally did it! and it will be soon on the
>   API, first it will appear in python API (yowsup) and later here in
>   PHP.
>
> The solution was to port the library.
>
> I just wanted to give this good news and wish you a merry christmas.
>
> Regards,
>
> The WhatsAPI Official Team

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. But now it is fixed. You can see their api. They have updated their api on [github](https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/releases) and fixed the encryption issue.

```
End to end encryption support: Now the API is able to encrypt and decrypt messages automatically
```

Comment: a using the one installed via Composer,  I still see encrypted messages when I call `$w->GetMessages()'`

Comment: This is my code:
$w->pollMessage();
$msgs = $w->GetMessages();
foreach ($msgs as $m) {
    var_dump($m);
}